# Linear gradient not working in :before pseudo

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a triangle cut effect on a div but its background is being rendered as a rectangle, unsure why:

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.parent {
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.parent:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: linear-gradient(190deg, transparent 20%, #FFFFFF 20.2%), linear-gradient(90deg, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

I'm not looking to 'cut' the `.parent` div. If possible I would like the `cut` to be on another div that sits on top of the parent div. The triangle cut will be white and the rest will be transparent (to show whatever is on the `.parent` div.

So using the image above as an example:

- Yellow div is `.parent`.
- White triangle is `.slant`.

Comment: do you want something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/h4o2tcs1/

Comment: @PR7 - Sort of, I've updated my question to provide an image. Your approach just rotates the rectangle, wondering if there's a way to avoid it being a rectangle in the first place?

Comment: Just increase height and update gradient to use the right colours `background: linear-gradient(190deg, yellow 74.2%, #fff 74.2%); height: 156%` https://jsfiddle.net/vg6t2xyn/ you will need play around with the size since everything you got is in percentages. Or you could just skew the before shape

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such effects using the clip-path property on your div elements.

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 50%);
```

The clip path property allows you to clip your elements into shapes. The polygon method gives you very fine control to create linear paths along the element. It is used by specifying the vertices of the polygon. A very large number of vertices can be specified to create complex shapes. They are specified clockwise.

http://www.cssplant.com/clip-path-generator

Use this tool to create shapes if you have trouble creating them through code yourself.

In this case. The first coordinates give you x = 0, y = 0; which is the top left corner. 
The next coordinate selects the right most corner.
Then the bottom right corner
Finally, the mid-section of the left edge at 50%.

The clip path will erase the background that lies outside this path.

Note: The div itself is still a rectangular block and elements inside can and will overflow out of the visible edge if height and padding is not handled properly.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.parent {
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 50%);
}

.parent-white {
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-white">
  <div class="parent">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat approach, but is there a way to do this with the clip path being on the child? It's just that I'm running across `z-index` issues: https://jsfiddle.net/ymoan8L9/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q7r40uxa/

You need to give the div.slant some height and width before you can clip it. I made it look like what I understood you want from the comments on your fiddle. Here: The container is a transparent div that contains a slanted yellow polygon, an overlay that covers the whole container, and then the content. If you do not want the overlay to flow out of the clipping. Just put that inside the slanted div, remove the position attributes and give it 50% width and 100% height.

Comment: Fiddle for reference to my comment above: https://jsfiddle.net/z2g49nye/

Answer (score 0):

your **before** background is working. just change the color and test.

like this example:

```
background: linear-gradient(190deg, transparent 20%, #000000 20.2%), linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0000 0%, #00ff0d 100%)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your code like below without the need of pseudo element:

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.parent {
  height: 200px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(yellow,yellow)                               top   /100% 30%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,yellow 50%,transparent 50.5%) bottom/100% 70%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

**Update**

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.parent {
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  position:relative;
}

.parent:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:30%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,#fff 50.5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I may have explained it poorly in my question, I would rather have the triangle effect in a separate div to avoid z-indexing issues. I've updated my question slightly

Comment: @Freddy as a side note, I was not cutting the parent on my first code so it's not like clip-path, it's a simple background